# How to debug heap corruption on Windows Store apps

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows to create DirectX Window Store app. I'm having issue with Critical error detected c0000374 that is the heap corruption. I've been googling and searching at Stackoverflow, but it seems the tools (gflags, dr memory, pageheap) that are suggested is not compatible with Windows Store.

So, How do i solve this problem ? Is there any debugging tools that are compatible with windows store app ?